# Expected behavior of the renderer for superscripts and subscripts in Word Open XML

Tags: openxml, wordprocessingml, wordml

It looks like ECMA specification for Word Open XML doesn't specify how to render "runs" with `vertAlign` attribute. Is there a document describing the expected behavior:

1. What font size to use for superscripts and subscripts?
2. For how much to shift the superscript/subscript text relatively to the baseline?

Just for reference, here's a document.xml generated by MS Word for a trivial document containing text "X²" (XML namespaces are omitted for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document>
  <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="4B8ED8F1" w14:textId="3891D3E1" 
         w:rsidR="00CE1223" w:rsidRDefault="00886D56">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>X</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidRPr="00886D56">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:vertAlign w:val="superscript"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>2</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00CE1223">
      <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" 
               w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="720"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [RunProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc803227(v%3Doffice.14)) elements has following two child elements which can be used to set the position and the font of a [Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc885013(v%3doffice.14)) which has a [VerticalTextAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.verticaltextalignment?view=openxml-2.8.1):

- The [RunFonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc879914(v%3Doffice.14)) element which can be used to set the type of font
- The [Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.position?view=openxml-2.8.1) element which can be used to lower or raise the the run in relation to its default baseline.

Using these elements you can create a run which is in superscript and has an adjusted font:

```
    // Creates an RunProperties instance and adds its children.
    public RunProperties GenerateRunProperties()
    {
        RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
        RunFonts runFonts1 = new RunFonts(){ Ascii = "Times New Roman", HighAnsi = "Times New Roman", ComplexScript = "Times New Roman" };
        FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize(){ Val = "48" };
        VerticalTextAlignment verticalTextAlignment1 = new VerticalTextAlignment(){ Val = VerticalPositionValues.Superscript };

        runProperties1.Append(runFonts1);
        runProperties1.Append(fontSize1);
        runProperties1.Append(verticalTextAlignment1);
        return runProperties1;
    }
```

This will output the follwing openxml:

```
<w:rPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
  <w:sz w:val="48" />
  <w:vertAlign w:val="superscript" />
</w:rPr>
```

And you can shift the vertical aligned run using these elements:

```
    // Creates an RunProperties instance and adds its children.
    public RunProperties GenerateRunProperties()
    {
        RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
        RunFonts runFonts1 = new RunFonts(){ Ascii = "Times New Roman", HighAnsi = "Times New Roman", ComplexScript = "Times New Roman" };
        Position position1 = new Position(){ Val = "-10" };
        FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize(){ Val = "48" };
        VerticalTextAlignment verticalTextAlignment1 = new VerticalTextAlignment(){ Val = VerticalPositionValues.Superscript };

        runProperties1.Append(runFonts1);
        runProperties1.Append(position1);
        runProperties1.Append(fontSize1);
        runProperties1.Append(verticalTextAlignment1);
        return runProperties1;
    }
```

Generating the follwing openXML:

```
<w:rPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
  <w:position w:val="-10" />
  <w:sz w:val="48" />
  <w:vertAlign w:val="superscript" />
</w:rPr>
```

Depending on the value that you assign to the position element the run will be raised or lowered in relation to its baseline:

- Positve  =>  Raised
- Negative =>  Lowered

Comment: I added a sample XML to the question. One can see it doesn't contain w:position or w:sz values. It looks like the specification is silent about real values which should be used for rendering (or I'm missing something).